# How to create custom sorting in sales grid custom column in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, custom, sorting, column, order-grid

I have created a custom column named printed which shows the invoice is printed or not and works well.

But how to apply sorting in in it like when i click on printed firstly it shows all data with pagination of printed yes then if i again click on it it sort by No.

So basically i want to know how to sort that data out by asc or desc order according to my printed value?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

by default you should be able to click on the column to sort value ASC/DESC, unless you have added a `<sortable>false</sortable>` node inside the setting node like this:

```
<column name="store_id" class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Purchase Point</label>
        <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
        <sortable>false</sortable>
    </settings>
</column>
```

If you have sortable node in there, delete it or set it to true.

If you mean to add a default sort when you go to the grid, without having to click on anything, then you have to add a sorting node.

More info here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-column.html